# KMZ file with image overlay - how to show on a website with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, kmz, map-overviews, wordpress

I have this image that contains map of an area, housing society to be exact, and I have successfully overlay it on Google Earth, my computer on anywhere else offline. Then I saved this place as a `.kmz` file. Image file type is `.png`.

`.kmz` files renders perfectly on Google Earth. I tried uploading this `.kmz` file to Google My Maps and it did not show the image. Initially I had a larger file (~20MB) but Google My Maps restricted me to use <5mb file and I did just just. Still *a layer* is not shown which I suspect is the image overlay.

I want to overlay this image to google maps and then show that map in my WordPress website.

Now what? Is there a work around? Any other way in Google to achieve that? Please direct as I couldn't find in two days of web search.

**PS.** *Assume I am not a coder, simple things like My Maps or a plugin would be ok*

**PS PS** *I want my site something like this one  https://www.seerab.com/g-9/*

Comment: If you're not a coder, this type of project is not for you.  To do this, you need to use the Google Maps API and add a data layer with the KML File. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml#layer

Comment: But my website is wordpress, and any theme change would destroy the manual code.

Comment: Make a Child Theme. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923879/how-to-create-a-child-theme-in-wordpress

Comment: Why is that a normal kml / kmz with data points / markers only can be shown a simple way but kml / kmz with image overlay has altogether different method for connecting to Google Maps?